# How to interpret custom instruction set?

Tags: c, regex, parsing, assembly, vm-implementation

I'm writing a virtual machine that directly executes my own assembly code. Here's an example below:

```
add r1, r2, r3 ; Add the values of reg2 and reg3 and store the result in reg1
```

As you can see the instructions are laid out as like this:

> INSTRUCTION PARAMETERS OPTIONAL_COMMENT

Would it be best to use regular expressions to parse this or would it be ok to parse it line by line and split each line up by spaces?

Comment: This isn't clear; how would one use a regex to interpret something?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sorry about that, I changed the question, I'd like to know if it's better to parse using regex or convert each line to an array and then split the array at each space to isolate each part of the instruction?

Comment: You might want to consider using a lexer and parser to do this. I don't know if that'd be too complex for what you're doing, though.

Comment: Don't you also want labels and assembler directives?

Comment: @kabb I'm just concerned that by using a lexer and parser would create too much overhead in the VM. I want it to be as lightweight as possible.

Comment: You should really consider parsing the input only once, and converting it to byte code which will be far more efficient (you are basically re-inventing python).

Comment: @pat I do plan on having assembler directives, I'm just not sure about the best way to parse the assembly because I think using something like lex and yacc would be overkill for simple instructions. Please correct me if I'm wrong or if you know of a better way to do it though.

Comment: @pat I thought that custom assembly was byte code, well byte code that hasn't been encoded as binary or hexadecimal. Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you plan to execute the instructions as you parse them?  If so, any instruction that gets executed more than once (like in a loop) is going to have to be parsed multiple times.  If you instead convert the text into byte code ahead of time, then your execution engine only has to look at the byte code, and consists of just a big switch statement.

Comment: I was planning on executing instructions as the VM see's them but now that I think about it, it's probably better to use byte code. The problem with byte code is that I have no idea how to encode strings for example, would I do it like this: 0001 = a, 0002 = b or is there a better way than that? Thanks for your answers by the way!

Comment: Take your add example above.  As assembly, that line takes 78 bytes (including the newline).  If you execute this directly, you will have to read 78 bytes each time.  With byte code, you could get it down to 1 or 2 bytes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49325/discussion-between-pat-and-user3318845)

Comment: (I wonder how this ended. Funny how OP equates "regular expression" with "lightweight".)